# Bootstrap Toggable Tabs works on localhost:3000 but not when I push to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, haml

Crazy. Can't explain it. Everything works fine locally. I can toggle between content panes locally.

I

git add .

git commit -am "toggle tabs"

git push heroku master

```
%ul.nav.nav-tabs{:id => "myTab"}
  %li
    %a.small-text-chart{:href => "#show-spread-visiting", "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      = "#{@event.visiting_team} points"
  %li
    %a.small-text-chart{:href => "#show-spread-home", "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      = "#{@event.home_team} points"
  %li.active
    %a.small-text-chart{:href => "#show-moneyline-visiting", "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      = "#{@event.visiting_team} moneyline"
  %li
    %a.small-text-chart{:href => "#show-moneyline-home", "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      = "#{@event.home_team} moneyline"
  %li
    %a.small-text-chart{:href => "#show-over-under", "data-toggle" => "tab"}
      = "Over/Under"


.tab-content
  .tab-pane{:id => "show-spread-visiting"}
  .tab-pane{:id => "show-spread-home"}
  .tab-pane.active{:id => "show-moneyline-visiting"}
  .tab-pane{:id => "show-moneyline-home"}
  .tab-pane{:id => "show-over-under"}
```

Above all this I have code that creates content for the tabs with javascript and Google ChartKick

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart4);
function drawChart4() {
var data4 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(#{@home_moneyline_movement_array});

var options4 = {
      title: 'Moneyline Movements for #{@event.home_team}'
    };

var chart4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('show-moneyline-home'));

    chart4.draw(data4, options4);

}
```

The tabs show up and I can hover over them and they change shading but I can't activate a tab or change the content panes below. Only the active panes work.

It all works fine on localhost! Help!

Comment: Did you check the debug console? Are there JS errors?

Comment: I will. What gets me is it works 100% local. Not on push to Heroku. How can I see if it is something in asset pipeline?